# MongoDB insert UUID only using middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, buffer, uuid

i dont know how to insert UUID into MongoDB properly.
For example:

```
db.users.insert({ uuid: UUID(buffer) })
```

Buffer must be 32 hex string and MongoDB natively dont create UUID, only stores this? I'm right? But where i create the random UUID, e.g through Node.js middleware i have a random UUID **11986aba-7c5a-4626-b354-80be23c25516**, so its a 36 length string and now i cant place it into `UUID(buffer)`. What i should doing with this UUID generated from node.js uuid module? And how later read this inserted values from MongoDB as a normal uuid string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BSON, hence MongoDB support the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) type. From the Mongo Shell, you can use the `UUID()` constructor to convert from a 32 hex-digits string to an UUID internal representation.

**From node.js**, using the `node-uuid` module you can easily generate [v1](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid#uuidv1options--buffer--offset) or [v4](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid#uuidv4options--buffer--offset) UUID and store them in a *buffer* object:

```
> my_uuid = uuid.v4(null, new Buffer(16))
<Buffer 91 ed c3 f0 20 36 4b f3 94 0c d3 d6 b0 a9 de 03>
```

You can then convert that to type 4 binary `SUBTYPE_UUID` (or the deprecated type 3 `SUBTYPE_UUID_OLD`):

```
> collection.insert({uuid: mongodb.Binary(my_uuid, mongodb.Binary.SUBTYPE_UUID)},
                    function(err, result) { /* ... */ })
```

**From the Mongo Shell**, you get back that value as:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557b2a390c59394b35236dc9"), "uuid" : BinData(4,"ke3D8CA2S/OUDNPWsKneAw==") }
```

Please note, the Mongo Shell [`UUID()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/UUID/) function will produce a type 3 `SUBTYPE_UUID_OLD` binary:

```
> db.test.insert({uuid:UUID('09352d90756741879c25e108d83290a2')})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557b2acc0c59394b35236dcb"), "uuid" : BinData(4,"ke3D8CA2S/OUDNPWsKneAw==") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557b2b7984ee2ba0375f4fc9"), "uuid" : BinData(3,"CTUtkHVnQYecJeEI2DKQog==") }
//                                                               ^
```

Comment: Thank you, actually i solved my problem. I think to remove hyphens this function will be better `uuid.v4(null, new Buffer(16)) // => <Buffer 09 35 2d 90 (...) >`, this return the new generated UUID into binary data, it's important, because MongoDB has a native function `UUID(32byteHex)` which convert this value from buffer to the MongoDB bin data. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/UUID/ storage UUID as a binary value provide better performance than string.

Comment: of course, but i dont have a reputation for voting here. :(

Comment: @user3075373 I've edited my answer with the informations you provided.  Is it better now ?

Comment: Yes! Actually i think this is the best way to storage UUID in MongoDB. :)